# Change icon when click button ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

i'm trying to change the icon when click the button its show hidden content 
i need to change up and down arrow icon

```
<button clear text-center (click)="toggle()">
 <ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown-circle"></ion-icon>
 </button>

<ion-col [hidden]="!visible" class="accountBalance animated slideInUp">
       <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <h3>limit</h3>
                <ion-note item-right>
                    <h2>&#x20B9; 55000.00</h2>
                </ion-note>
          </ion-item>
<ion-list></ion-col>
```

file.ts

```
visible = false;
  toggle() {
   this.visible = !this.visible;
  }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use `*ngIf` directive here to show conditional icon.

```
<button clear text-center (click)="toggle()">
   <ion-icon name="arrow-drop down-circle" *ngIf="!visible"></ion-icon>
   <ion-icon name="arrow-drop up-circle" *ngIf="visible"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

You could use `name` property instead of creating two different ion-icon

```
<button clear text-center (click)="toggle()">
   <ion-icon 
       [name]="visible ? 'arrow-drop up-circle' :'arrow-drop down-circle'">
   </ion-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: I believe the first example is the cleanest solution.

Comment: Nice, but only work for one ion-icon, I think its bad practice to do this with a lot of ion-icon

Answer (score 11):

You can create a conditional in the `name=` attribute

```
<ion-icon [name]="visible ? 'arrow-dropdown' : 'arrow-dropup'"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: this is more ionic way than the one up marked as the answer

Answer (score 3):

This took me forever to find since there are very few examples out there for toggling icons. However, I used the [Ionic 2 Icons Doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#icons) and came up with this:

ts:

```
class ToggleIconsPage {
    buttonIcon: string = "home";

    toggleIcon(getIcon: string) {

      if (this.buttonIcon === 'star') {
        this.buttonIcon = "home";
      }
      else if (this.buttonIcon === 'home') {
        this.buttonIcon = "star";
      }
   }
}
```

html:

```
<button #myButton ion-button icon-only (click)="toggleIcon()">
    <ion-icon [name]="buttonIcon"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

See my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/palmtreetheory/pen/dWKQgb) as an example.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I needed to solve the problem, except that my code required it to be solved more programmatically, since I have numerous items being added. Initially, I tried using a variable `visible`, as in the above example. However, since I added multiple items, using the `visible` variable would toggle all of them on and off. Instead, I did the following, since each of my items had a unique identifier `key`:

```
export class WhateverPage {
  private visible = []; 
...
...
...
  toggle(key) {
    var index = this.visible.indexOf(key);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.visible.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      this.visible.push(key);
    }
  }
```

AND

```
<ion-icon ios="ios-add-circle" md="md-add-circle" (click)="toggle(key)" *ngIf="!visible.includes(key)"></ion-icon> 
<ion-icon ios="ios-checkmark" md="md-checkmark" (click)="toggle(key)" *ngIf="visible.includes(key)"></ion-icon>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This maybe of help. I am using (Ionic 5);**

**a.ts**

```
  //declare this globally
  fieldTextType: boolean;

  toggleFieldTextType(){
    this.fieldTextType = !this.fieldTextType;
  }
```

**a.html**

```
<ion-row class="ion-padding">
  <ion-input formControlName="Username" type="text" placeholder="Enter phone.">
    <ion-icon class="ion-padding-left" name="person-outline"></ion-icon>
  </ion-input>
</ion-row>
<ion-row class="ion-padding">
  <ion-input formControlName="password" [type]="fieldTextType ? 'text' : 'password'" placeholder="Enter password..">
    <ion-icon  [name]="fieldTextType ? 'eye-outline' : 'eye-off-outline'" (click)="toggleFieldTextType()" class="ion-padding-left"></ion-icon>
  </ion-input>
</ion-row>
```

[image: screenshot]